# Directed acyclic graph with topological sort

Tags: c++, c++11, sorting, graph

I have here a class which represents a directed acyclic graph (`Graph`) and a vertex in the graph (`Vertex`). The vertices are stored in an adjacency list. It has the ability to find a vertex's indegree, and to find a topological sort order. The graph does not own the vertices.

I'm particularly interested in comments regarding correctness and performance.

### `Vertex` header

```
#include <string>

class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex(std::string name, int weight = 1);
    virtual ~Vertex() = default;

    const std::string& name() const { return _name; }
    int weight() const { return _weight; }
protected:
    std::string _name;
    int         _weight;
};
```

### `Vertex` definitions

```
Vertex::Vertex(std::string name, int weight)
    : _name(std::move(name))
    , _weight(weight)
{}
```

### `Graph` header

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

class Graph
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    using VertexMap     = std::unordered_map<Vertex*, T>;
    using AdjacencyList = VertexMap<std::vector<Vertex*>>;

    void addEdge(Vertex* u, Vertex* v);

    std::vector<Vertex*> topoSort();

    VertexMap<int> indegrees() const;
    int indegree(Vertex*) const;

    const AdjacencyList& adjacencyList() const;
private:
    AdjacencyList _vertices;
};
```

### `Graph` definitions

```
void Graph::addEdge(Vertex* u, Vertex* v)
{
    _vertices[v];               // initialise adjacency list for v
    _vertices[u].push_back(v);  // add v as being adjacent to u
}

enum Colour { White, Grey, Black };

void topoSortVertex(Vertex* vertex,
                    Colour& colour,
                    const Graph::AdjacencyList& adjacencyList,
                    Graph::VertexMap<Colour>& visited,
                    std::vector<Vertex*>& sorted)
{
    colour = Grey;

    for (Vertex* neighbour : adjacencyList.at(vertex))
    {
        Colour& neighbour_colour = visited[neighbour];
        if (neighbour_colour == White)
        {
            topoSortVertex(neighbour, neighbour_colour, adjacencyList, visited, sorted);
        }
        else
        if (neighbour_colour == Grey)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("cycle in graph");
        }
    }

    colour = Black;
    sorted.push_back(vertex);
}

std::vector<Vertex*> Graph::topoSort()
{
    VertexMap<int> indegs = indegrees();

    std::vector<Vertex*> sorted;
    sorted.reserve(indegs.size());

    VertexMap<Colour> visited;
    visited.reserve(indegs.size());

    for (auto& pair : indegs)
    {
        if (pair.second == 0) // vertex has indegree of 0
        {
            Vertex* vertex = pair.first;
            Colour& colour = visited[vertex];
            if (colour == White)
            {
                topoSortVertex(vertex, colour, _vertices, visited, sorted);
            }
        }
    }

    return sorted;
}

Graph::VertexMap<int> Graph::indegrees() const
{
    VertexMap<int> indegrees;

    for (auto& pair : _vertices)
    {
        indegrees[pair.first]; // initialise indegree for this vertex
        for (Vertex* neighbour : pair.second)
        {
            ++indegrees[neighbour];
        }
    }

    return indegrees;
}

int Graph::indegree(Vertex* v) const
{
    return indegrees().at(v);
}

const Graph::AdjacencyList& Graph::adjacencyList() const
{
    return _vertices;
}
```

### Exemplar

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Graph g;
    Vertex v2  {  "2" };
    Vertex v3  {  "3" };
    Vertex v5  {  "5" };
    Vertex v7  {  "7" };
    Vertex v8  {  "8" };
    Vertex v9  {  "9" };
    Vertex v10 { "10" };
    Vertex v11 { "11" };

    g.addEdge(&v7,  &v11);
    g.addEdge(&v7,  &v8);
    g.addEdge(&v5,  &v11);
    g.addEdge(&v3,  &v8);
    g.addEdge(&v3,  &v10);
    g.addEdge(&v8,  &v9);
    g.addEdge(&v11, &v9);
    g.addEdge(&v9,  &v2);

    /*
     *    3   7    5
     *   / \ / \  /
     * 10   8   11
     *       \ /
     *        9
     *        |
     *        2
     */

    std::cout << "adjacency list:\n";
    for (auto& pair : g.adjacencyList())
    {
        std::cout << pair.first->name() << ": ";
        for (const Vertex* neighbour : pair.second)
            std::cout << neighbour->name() << ", ";
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "indegrees:\n";
    for (auto& pair : g.indegrees())
        std::cout << pair.first->name() << ": " << pair.second << '\n';

    std::cout << "topoSort:\n";
    for (Vertex* v : g.topoSort())
        std::cout << v->name() << ", ";
    std::cout << '\n';

    // add cycle
    g.addEdge(&v9, &v3);
    try
    {
        g.topoSort();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

### Output

> ```
> adjacency list:
> 2: 
> 9: 2, 
> 10: 
> 3: 8, 10, 
> 5: 11, 
> 8: 9, 
> 7: 11, 8, 
> 11: 9, 
> indegrees:
> 7: 0
> 11: 2
> 5: 0
> 8: 2
> 3: 0
> 10: 1
> 9: 2
> 2: 1
> topoSort:
> 2, 9, 11, 8, 7, 5, 10, 3, 
> cycle in graph
> ```

[Here is the code running on Ideone](http://ideone.com/JObMRV).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Performance

A very cache friendly representation of a directed graph is the [forward star representation](http://web.archive.org/web/20150927090755/http://www.ncgia.ucsb.edu/giscc/units/u064/u064.html). Basically it's a single vector containing all edges sorted by their head node, with another index vector mapping a node to its first outgoing edge.

## Correctness

Your definition of a "cycle" is somewhat non-standard? Usually, a cycle in a directed graph means that you can get back to a particular vertex. In your example, adding a vertex from 9 -> 8 -> 7 would make it cyclic. But I guess, it depends on what you're after.

Likewise, your sort order is reversed to the standard definition as given in Cormen:

> If there is an edge `(u,v)` then `u` appears before `v` in the ordering.

## Code style

```
class Vertex
{
public:
    virtual ~Vertex() = default;
}
```

No need to `default` the destructor here.

Consider making `colour`an attribute at `CVertex` instead of a separate vector. You're only shifting around pointers to it anyway so no need to have it separate.

Make `indegrees` a member of `Graph`. At the moment, every call to `Graph::indegree` iterates the whole vertex list.

In `Graph::topoSort`:

```
    if (colour == White)
```

I think that could be `assert (colour == White)`. It doesn't have an indegree so it shouldn't have been visited before.

Comment: Is this post using a link to the Web Archive in case the original goes down in the future? I'm asking because it's currently still up.